# How to prevent unwanted web-to-lead character conversion

Tags: web2lead, character-encoding

Arabic user data that was captured with our web-to-lead form occasionally ends up [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake#Arabic) in our lead table. A user would type something like:

> الإعلان العالمى لحقوق الإنسان

When we retrieve the message from the database, it reads:

> ï»¿Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ø¹Ù„Ø§Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù‰ Ù„Ø­Ù‚ÙˆÙ‚ Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ù†Ø³Ø§Ù†

The form is in an embedded iframe page with these tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />

    <!-- other header elements -->

  </head>

  <body>
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="post">

   <!-- other body elements -->

  </body>

</html>
```

After first noticing the problem I added the `accept-charset` attribute to the form tag. Is there anything more I can do in the page markup that can prevent the problem?

Since the character scramble only happens occasionally, what is the best way to try and replicate / isolate the problem? We have several triggers running after a lead insert and logging all web-to-lead activity generate a fantastic amount of raw data to wade through to try and spot the occasional culprit. Not sure what to look for anyway. User agent signature? Characters falling outside/inside a certain unicode range?

Thanks!

Comment: The string ï»¿Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ø¹… is the Arabic input when it has been represented as UTF-8 with BOM and the bytes of that representation are then misinterpreted as if they were windows-1252 encoded data. From the outside, we cannot really tell where this problem is generated. It is possible that the data is being viewed under conditions that enforce windows-1252 interpretation, e.g. when HTTP specify it in a `Content-Type` header, overriding the `meta` tag.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela with "It is possible that the data is being viewed ..." do you mean the data is not stored as UTF-8 in salesforce and then when we view the case record in a browser the transcoding takes place? This is definitely not the case. I can see properly encoded Arabic and this gibberish on the same case inside salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

JannieT, I think the issue may be due to the [character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.2.2) specified on the pages where your Web-to-Lead form is placed. For example, the same Web-to-Lead [form on a page](http://pastebin.com/5XDZ0MJU) that uses UTF-8 encoding will produce entirely different data in your org when placed on a [page using ISO 8859-1 encoding](http://pastebin.com/43z3dNmQ).

Can you see whether this is the case with the pages that are producing problematic leads? Take a closer look at the `meta` elements on your W2L pages, and check to see whether `charset` is being set to **UTF-8**.

Comment: Thanks Marty. There is just one page that is producing the problem and I have posted the code. Can you see a problem with it?

Comment: Hello, JannieT, are you referring to the code sample you wrote in your original question? Is that the only page that's being embedded in all places where you've deployed the Web-to-Lead form?

Comment: Marty, yes and yes.